# How can I convert Firestore Timestamp to Java LocalDate?

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore

I'm retrieving a Timestamp from firestore, but I want to be able to display it in the following format: `June 25, 2021`

Is there a way to convert the Timestamp to a LocalDate variable in Java so that I can use the following: `date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.LONG));`

Answer (score 0):

The Timestamp should be a `com.google.protobuf.Timestamp` object.  The utils in [`com.google.protobuf.util.Timestamps`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/util/Timestamps) has methods to help you convert to and from `com.google.protobuf.Timestamp`.